# Both my EditText fields are responding to pressing the return key

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have two EditText fields, one for username and one for password. When I finish typing the username and press enter, I want focus to switch to the password. When I finish password and press return, some code is also run.

My problem is that when I finish typing the code for the username and press return, both segments of code are run. Below is my code:

```
userNameEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && userNameEditText.hasFocus()) {
           passwordEditText.requestFocus();
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
});

passwordEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && passwordEditText.hasFocus()) {
            attemptLogin(userNameEditText, passwordEditText);
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(passwordEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

What should I do so that only the code for the selected EditText is run when I press enter on the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you haven't tested for the type of KeyEvent.

The first listener is being fired when event.getAction()==ACTION_DOWN and then the second is being fired when event.getAction()==ACTION_UP.

You need to change your listener to check for the type of action as well as key, I would recommend only firing your action on ACTION_UP.

Comment: ACTION_UP still input a carriage return before running the code, ACTION_DOWN worked perfectly though